# How to consume the minimal input with fuzzy parsing with ANTLR 4.4+

Tags: parsing, antlr4

I am trying to extract condition between two keywords (IF & THEN in this example) without specifying the full grammar.
The input to the parser begin with the first keyword.
Input example could be : "IF  A < 10 OR B> 5 THEN A = A + 1; B=6; ENDIF; IF A < 10 THEN A = 100 ENDIF"
From that input, i want to extract the condition : "A < 10 OR B> 5".

We did it with ANTLR 3.5 but unable to make it work with ANLTR 4.4 & 4.5.

** 3.5 Grammar **

```
grammar FuzzyTest3;
options 
{
   output=AST;
   language=Java;
}
@header 
{package fuzzytest;}
@lexer::header  
{package fuzzytest;}
ifrule: IF .* THEN;
IF : 'IF';
THEN : 'THEN';
IDENTIFIER : ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_')*;
SEPARATOR : (  '<' | '>' | ':' '(' | ')' | '-' | '+' | '=' | ';' );
WS  : ( ' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n' | '\u000C')+
{
  { $channel = HIDDEN; }
};
```

** 4.4 Grammar **

```
grammar FuzzyTest4;

ifrule: IF (.)*? THEN;
//ifrule: IF .* THEN; //same result
IF : 'IF';
THEN : 'THEN';
IDENTIFIER : ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_')*;
SEPARATOR : (  '<' | '>' | ':' '(' | ')' | '-' | '+' | '=' | ';' );
WS  : ( ' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n' | '\u000C') -> channel(HIDDEN);
```

With ANTLR 3.5:

```
ParserRuleReturnScope rulereturn = parser.ifrule(); 
result = parser.input.toString(rulereturn.start, rulereturn.stop);
System.out.println("TOKENS: "+result);

My output is : 
"TOKENS: IF  A < 10 OR B> 5 THEN"
```

With ANLTR 4.4:

```
ParserRuleContext rulereturn = parser.ifrule(); 
result = parser.getInputStream().getText(rulereturn.start, rulereturn.stop);
System.out.println("TOKENS: "+result);

My output is :
"line 2:76 no viable alternative at input '<EOF>'
TOKENS: IF  A < 10 OR B> 5 THEN A = A + 1; B=6; ENDIF; IF A < 10 THEN A = 100 ENDIF"
```

Anyone have an idea? suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is (what that example):

```
ifrule: IF  condition;
condition: ~(THEN|IF) condition | ~(THEN|IF);
```